# Why is this file not loading in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this JavaScript file, which is throwing an exception,

```
index.html:701 GET http://localhost:45856/fonts/webfontrr0a7.woff42?v=9.9.1
```

[image]

Clearly file is uploading and I can see it in chrome sources, but why is it complainging about fonts ?

Comment: What's in the network tab?

Comment: @PraveenKumar in network tab, it is complaining about webfontrr0a7.woff42?v=9.9.1 file

Comment: @Mathematics There, what's the status code?

Comment: @PraveenKumar 404, but they are uploading though, seems like they are the ones that take most time uploading, 389ms

Comment: Er... What's the server?

Comment: IIS latest one, running it in VS 2012 premium

Comment: Crazy... Can you screenshot the view clicking on the 404 entry in the Network tab with the right part shown fully?

Comment: Such errors mostly occur when your single and double quotes are messed up carefully check any missing quotes in <link> <script> and html tags